# SPFX writing logs

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx

what would be the preferred approach to write custom logs for SPFX apps other than writing in lists or using Azure insights ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are limited because spfx code is browser-based.

The "correct" answer is to use Azure App Insights, or some other instrumentation provider like Google analytics. They're easy to set up and require nothing else to build.

Your alternative would be to publish an API and log to that over HTTP. You can use any storage mechanism you wish, but you have to write the code, manage security, host it, and support it yourself.